# Mondrian Schema uniqueMembers

Tags: olap, olap-cube, mondrian, saiku

I am using Mondrian with Pentaho and Saiku to do OLAP analysis on a MySQL database.
I have a data warehouse with 2 dimensions (beneficiary and member) linking to a fact table. 
Beneficiary has the following fields: beneficiary_type1, beneficiary_type2, beneficiary_type3.
Member has the a field for gender.

I have created a Mondrian schema defined with the following:

```
<Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="beneficiary_id" highCardinality="false" name="beneficiary">
  <Hierarchy visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="id">
    <Table name="beneficiary">
    </Table>
    <Level name="beneficiary_type1" visible="true" column="beneficiary_type1" type="String" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
    </Level>
    <Level name="beneficiary_type2" visible="true" column="beneficiary_type2" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
    </Level>
    <Level name="beneficiary_type3" visible="true" column="beneficiary_type3" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
    </Level>
  </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>

<Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="member_id" highCardinality="false" name="member">
  <Hierarchy visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="id">
    <Table name="member">
    </Table>
    <Level name="gender" visible="true" column="gender" type="String" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
    </Level>
  </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

I want to be able to view (separately): 
the amount of males / females for beneficiary_type1,
the amount of males / females for beneficiary_type2,
the amount of males / females for beneficiary_type3,

If I drag gender over beneficiary_type1 then I see the following, which is correct:

[image: olap1]

If I drag gender over beneficiary_type2 then I see the following, which is incorrect:

[image: olap2]

As this is the beneficiary_type2 column, grouped by benefiiary_type1 as can be seen when adding both the fields:

[image]

When viewing gender over beneficiary_type2, I expect to see only 2 rows, namely one for "Adults" and another for "Children to 19". From what I have read it seems that the uniqueMembers attribute should be set on the beneficiary_type2 level, but this results in the following:

[image]

Which yields the correct numbered results but the rows are still displayed as if grouped by beneficiary_type1. Also, this way does not allow for the generation of beneficiary_type2 grouped correctly under beneficiary_type1 as in the third image (the numbered results are never grouped according to the parent level).

How should I structure the schema to have the number of rows determined by the parent level that I have included in the analysis? (dragged into the cube using saiku) i.e. when dragging in beneficiary_type1 and beneficiary_type2 then beneficiary_type2 is grouped according to beneficiary_type1 (like the third image), if only beneficiary_type2 then it is grouped according to its own unique values (2 rows, one for "Adults" and one for "Children to 19").

I am relatively new to OLAP, so there might be some basic concepts that I do not understand. Please don't hesitate to branch out with any explanation.

-------------------- Update --------------------

As explained by @nsousa, members inside the same hierarchy imply a parent child relationship. Would a correct change to the schema be the following?

```
<Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="beneficiary_id" highCardinality="false" name="beneficiary">
  <Hierarchy visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="id">
    <Table name="beneficiary">
    </Table>
    <Level name="beneficiary_type1" visible="true" column="beneficiary_type1" type="String" uniqueMembers="true" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
    </Level>
  </Hierarchy>
  <Hierarchy visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="id">
    <Table name="beneficiary">
    </Table>
    <Level name="beneficiary_type2" visible="true" column="beneficiary_type2" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
    </Level>
  </Hierarchy>
  <Hierarchy visible="true" hasAll="true" primaryKey="id">
    <Table name="beneficiary">
    </Table>
    <Level name="beneficiary_type3" visible="true" column="beneficiary_type3" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="Regular" hideMemberIf="Never">
    </Level>
  </Hierarchy>
</Dimension>
```

Am I correct in understanding that an alternative solution would be to load 3 separate dimensions for the beneficiary table? Would this imply that 3 separate tables (one for each beneficiary member) need to exist in the database as well, or can the same table be used for multiple dimensions? Obviously, having a database table for each member is not ideal, are there any advantages of doing it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your beneficiary_type2 level is a descendant of beneficiary_type1. As such, even if the member names match, two "Adults" on level 2 are not the same member unless they also have the same parent.

As they have different parents, they are cousins that share a name. Hence, you get multiple rows.

The only safe way to do what you want is to split the various levels into multiple dimensions/hierarchies instead of having a parent-child hierarchy.

On different hierarchies, there's no relationship between type1 and type2, and you get only the two distinct strings you want.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and clear answer nsousa. I have edited my question, could you please check if my understanding is correct? Anything else related to this that would be good to take into account?

Comment: Even if you set uniqueMembers to true, it won't make a difference. What uniqueMembers="true" does is it allows mondrian to filter directly on the level, instead of adding multiple conditions to the Where clause of SQL, one for each level. If you want your 2nd level to be treated as if it were a 1st level, then you need to create different hierarchies.